# SQL. поменять строки и столбы местами с помощью VIEW

Tags: sql

Всем привет.

Имеется 2 таблицы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно перейти из одной в другую и наоборот.
Используя VIEW или виртуальные таблицы.

Буду благодарен за совет.

Comment: А какой диалект?

Comment: честно, не понял про диалект,

Comment: но видно, что нужно развернуть таблицу. строки в столбы и наоборот

Comment: пробую пока через WITH решить, но пока не очень

Comment: ну вот есть ms-sql, есть mysql, есть oracle, есть postgresql, у вас что?

Comment: postgresql   советуют еще о LETERAL join подумать

Comment: https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/tablefunc  --- посмотрите `crosstab`

Comment: здесь еще вопрос как значения столбцов, стали значением строк

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот пример

```
select a.student, b.*
from result_table_1 a
  cross join lateral (
     values 
       (a.h, 'H'),
       (a.z, 'Z'),
       (a.e, 'E')
  ) as b(atyp, prozent)
order by student, atyp;
```

Как [тут](https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/unpivot-with-postgres/)

Comment: да, это работает, спасибо

Comment: @Ponoptikum Ессли ответ помог то можете пометить как полезный под стрелками